# okta + .net web api - how to get authenticated user email & name (profile scope data)

Tags: asp.net-web-api, okta, okta-api

My web api server implements the same code as you can see from okta guide : 
https://developer.okta.com/quickstart/#/widget/dotnet/aspnet4

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{
    // Configure JWT Bearer middleware
    // with an OpenID Connect Authority

    var authority = "https://{yourOktaDomain}.com/oauth2/default";

    var configurationManager = new ConfigurationManager<OpenIdConnectConfiguration>(
        authority + "/.well-known/openid-configuration",
        new OpenIdConnectConfigurationRetriever(),
        new HttpDocumentRetriever());

    app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active,
        TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = "api://default",
            ValidIssuer = authority,
            IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (token, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
            {
                var discoveryDocument = Task.Run(() => configurationManager.GetConfigurationAsync()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                return discoveryDocument.SigningKeys;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Authentication works but how I get **autheneticated user email and name** from 'profile' scope ? 
What I see is this :
[image]

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well , after many hours wasted on this , the solution is these changes :

- send id_token instead of session_token
- `ValidAudience = "api://default"` to `ValidAudience = "your-application-client-id"`
- `ValidateAudience = true`